# How can I get the rails/coffee-rails gem to use the latest coffee-script compiler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

My coffee scripts contain chained calls to an object, which compile correctly when using the latest compiler (manually), but fail to compile correctly when using the rails/coffee-script tools in the asset pipeline.

What is the best way to get around this? Preferably, get it to use the latest coffee compiler.

Here is a sample of my coffee script, with chained calls

```
// coffeescript
someObject
  .chainedMethod 'home', {
      paramA: 'a'
      paramB: 'b'
    }
  .chainedMethod 'signin', {
      paramA: 'xx'
      paramB: 'yy'
      controller: 'SignInController'
    }
```

When correctly compiled, it looks like:

```
// javascript
someObject.chainedMethod('home', {
  paramA: 'a',
  paramB: 'b'
}).chainedMethod('signin', {
  paramA: 'xx',
  paramB: 'yy',
  controller: 'SignInController'
});
```

Rails 4.0 asset pipeline produces the following:

```
// buggy javascript
someObject.chainedMethod('home', {
  paramA: 'a',
  paramB: 'b'
}.chainedMethod('signin', {
  paramA: 'xx',
  paramB: 'yy',
  controller: 'SignInController'
}));
```

Comment: I've also opened a bug here https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/issues/54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I managed to resolve this by upgrading the coffee-script-source gem. It turns out that the rails/coffee-rails gem is simply getting the underlying coffee-script and coffee-script-source gems to do the real work. The coffee-script-source gem is kept in sync with the latest sources on http://coffeescript.org/

Running `bundle update coffee-script-source` to get the latest and restarting the rails server resolved the issue.

Here are the gem versions after the fix.

```
coffee-script-source-1.7.0
coffee-script-2.2.0
coffee-rails-4.0.1
```